# TEXT processing with awk

Tags: text-processing, awk, text

I have text like below:

```
select {{112,department}},{{112,client}},{{112,place}} from table where id=1 and {{112,cgid}} and {{113,evid}}
```

I need to write into a file as

```
{{112,department}}
{{112,client}}
{{112,place}}
{{112,cgid}} 
{{113,evid}}
```

with each item on its own line.

I tried `awk -F '[{}]' '{print $2}'` but it prints only the first occurrence and only the data without `{}`. Adding suffix and the prefix `{}` gives a syntax error?

#### Additional requirement

- to replace `{{va1,val2}}` in the query with a single value which I'll get after querying a table using `val1` and `val2`.

Comment: Is this a typo? `{{112,cgid}} and {{113,evid}`?

Comment: nope..i am actually giving some dummy data instead of original data.. the patter {{}} may occur even in where

Comment: ouch.  completely changed the question.

Comment: @steve - yup....I should've closed as unclear, my bad.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Alternatively with `sed`:

```
sed 's/select //;s/ from[^}]* //;s/},{/}\n{/g;s/}}{{/}}\n{{/g;s/\s*and\s*/\n/g'
```

#### Example

```
$ echo 'select {{112,department}},{{112,client}},{{112,place}} from table where id=1 and {{112,cgid}} and {{113,evid}' | \
   sed 's/select //;s/ from[^{]*//;s/},{/}\n{/g;s/}}{{/}}\n{{/g;s/\s*and\s*/\n/g'
{{112,department}}
{{112,client}}
{{112,place}}
{{112,cgid}}
{{113,evid}
```

*How it works:*

- `s/select //;` - deletes `select` from the beginning
- `s/ from[^{]*//;` - deletes from the `from.*` up to the first `{`
- `s/},{/}\n{/g;` - converts all the `},{` to `}\n{`
- `s/}}{{/}}\n{{/g;` - convert all the `}}{{` to `}}\n{{`
- `s/\s*and\s*/\n/g'` - convert all the `and` to `\n`

Answer (score 1):

you could use the *grep* command, in manual page you would find:

> grep  searches  for  PATTERN  in  each  FILE.   A FILE of “-” stands for standard input.  If no FILE is given, recursive searches examine the working directory, and nonrecursive searches read standard input.  By default, grep prints the matching lines.
>
> -o, --only-matching
>       Print only the matched (non-empty) parts of a matching line, with each 
>   such part on a separate output line.
>
> -e PATTERN, --regexp=PATTERN
>        Use  PATTERN as the pattern.  If this option is used multiple times or is combined with the -f (--file) option, search for all patterns given.  This option can be used to protect a pattern beginning with “-”.

for your question:

```
echo 'select {{112,department}},{{112,client}},{{112,place}} from table where id=1 and {{112,cgid}} and {{113,evid}}' | grep -o -e "{\{2\}[^{]*}\{2\}"
```

- `{\{2\}` means *{* symbol occurs exactly twice.
- `[^{]*`  means any chars any times, except *{*.
- `}\{2\}` means *}* symbols occurs exactly twice.

the result will:

```
{{112,department}}
{{112,client}}
{{112,place}}
{{112,cgid}}
{{113,evid}}
```

Answer (score 0):

How about this.  Replace each "}," in field 2 with just "} ", and then print field 2.

```
awk '{gsub(/},/,"} ",$2);print $2}' file
```

Or in `sed`.  Pluck out the text between "select" and "from", and replace each "}," with "} ".

```
sed 's/^select \({.*}\) from .*/\1/;s/},/} /g' file
```

Comment: thank u.. this worked but this pattern may occur anywhere in the query.. not only i the select..

Answer (score 0):

With `perl`:

```
perl -lne 'print for /\{\{.*?\}\}(?=.*from \S+ where)/g'
```

With GNU `grep` or compatible:

```
grep -Po '\{\{.*?\}\}(?=.*from \S+ where)'
```

With GNU `awk`:

```
gawk -v FPAT='[{][{][^}]*[}][}]' '{
  sub(/from [[:space:]]+ where.*/, "")
  for (i = 1; i <= NF; i++) print $i}'
```

For all, you can feed the input on stdin or as a filename argument.

Comment: i am sorry. to ask this... how can i specify the input file in the above commands.. i m totally new to this

Comment: Add it as file arg. to them like `grep .... <file>`.

Comment: perl -lne 'print for /\{\{.*?\}\}/g' input.hql. am i right ? this didnt work

Comment: For the `perl` one do this `cat <file> | perl ...`

Comment: cat input.hql | perl -lne 'print for /\{\{.*?\}\}/g' this didnt give any o/p.. shd v capture the o/p for display?

Answer (score 0):

I'd use `grep` rather than `awk`. Here the `-P` flag asks `grep` to use PCRE regular expressions rather than its default (so that `.*?` matches *as little as possible*), and the `-o` flag gets `grep` to print only matching components:

```
grep -Po '{{.*?}}'
```

Example:

```
grep -Po '{{.*?}}' <<<'select {{112,department}},{{112,client}},{{112,place}} from table where id=1 and {{112,cgid}} and {{113,evid}}'
{{112,department}}
{{112,client}}
{{112,place}}
{{112,cgid}}
{{113,evid}}
```

There is no `{{va1,val2}}` to match in your query so the "additional requirement" is moot. Or are you generalising to the matched entities such as `{{112,department}}`? If so, you need to explain what is to be done, because to *replace [them] in the query with a single value which I'll get [later]* is too broad a requirement to address with explicit code.

Comment: thank u this worked... now how can i capture the first value from {{}}. like 112 from {{112,department}}. i tried var1=`echo $line | awk -F '[{{}}]' '{print $2}' | awk -F '[,]' '{print $1}'` its not working. the same command works for single {}